# How do I precompile dotnetcore assemblies using NGEN?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, precompile, ngen

The process of debugging my dornetcore solution has been painfully slow.  It takes up to a half a minute or more just to startup. My release builds are faster, but are still unacceptable.

After deploying my app on the server, I precompiled its assemblies and the speed up was night and day. Unfortunately, I am not sure how I would go about precompiling assemblies on my local development environment.

Most of my app's dependencies are nuget packages. They are copies of the packages buried in strange locations. I am also not sure how to bake the NGEN compilation into my VS build so they are executed when the packages are updated or restored.

Any ideas?